# Unpivot a query in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, split, flatten, google-query-language, textjoin

I have a query in google sheets that i use to filter table. I then need to UNPIVOT (flatten) this query output to get it in a Database style.

Query:

```
=query('Variables VAC'!A5:AP500,"select 
A,B,AB,AC,AD,AE,AF,AG,AH,AI,AJ,AK,AL,AM,AN,AO,AP where A is not null ")
```

gives this result

| Code | Subc | 30/09/2022 | 31/10/2022 | 30/11/2022 | 31/12/2022 | 31/01/2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C0000 | 0000-001 | 844662.7140 | 874490.22108 | 905365.84788 | 937321.32072 | 970422.72499 |
| C0000 | 0000-002 | -106427.5020 | -110185.76786 | -114076.09683 | -118102.48641 | -122273.26335 |
| C1003 | 1003-001 | -399.6625 | -405.66250 | -411.75000 | -417.92500 | -424.20000 |
| C1002 | 1002-001 | -28380.6672 | -29382.87143 | -30420.29249 | -31493.99638 | -32606.20356 |
| C1004 | 1004-001 | -88911.3044 | -117753.57147 | -103621.88452 | -137239.27133 | -120781.71291 |
| C0000 | 0000-003 | -11414.3610 | -11817.43542 | -12234.67362 | -12666.50433 | -13113.82061 |
| C1008 | 1008-001 | 79989.2273 | 81802.26833 | 83710.02368 | 85716.62069 | 87831.43170 |
| C1012 | 1012-004 | 11110.0000 | 11221.10000 | 11333.31000 | 11446.64000 | 11561.11000 |
| C1001 | 1001-001 | 134808.1692 | 139568.63928 | 144496.38932 | 149596.48279 | 154879.46691 |

i need to have this query "unpivoted" to get to this result:

| Month | Code | Sbc | Amount | CC |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 30/09/2022 | C0000 | 1007-000 | 844662.714 | VAC |
| 31/10/2022 | C0000 | 1007-000 | 874490.2211 | VAC |
| 30/11/2022 | C0000 | 1007-000 | 905365.8479 | VAC |
| 31/12/2022 | C0000 | 1007-000 | 937321.3207 | VAC |
| 31/01/2023 | C0000 | 1007-000 | 970422.725 | VAC |
| 30/09/2022 | C0000 | 1007-007 | -106427.502 | VAC |
| 31/10/2022 | C0000 | 1007-007 | -110185.7679 | VAC |
| 30/11/2022 | C0000 | 1007-007 | -114076.0968 | VAC |
| 31/12/2022 | C0000 | 1007-007 | -118102.4864 | VAC |
| 31/01/2023 | C0000 | 1007-007 | -122273.2633 | VAC |
| 30/09/2022 | C1003 | 1007-008 | -399.6625 | VAC |
| 31/10/2022 | C1003 | 1007-008 | -405.6625 | VAC |
| 30/11/2022 | C1003 | 1007-008 | -411.75 | VAC |
| 31/12/2022 | C1003 | 1007-008 | -417.925 | VAC |
| 31/01/2023 | C1003 | 1007-008 | -424.2 | VAC |
| 30/09/2022 | C1002 | 1007-009 | -28380.66719 | VAC |
| 31/10/2022 | C1002 | 1007-009 | -29382.87143 | VAC |
| 30/11/2022 | C1002 | 1007-009 | -30420.29249 | VAC |
| 31/12/2022 | C1002 | 1007-009 | -31493.99638 | VAC |
| 31/01/2023 | C1002 | 1007-009 | -32606.20356 | VAC |
| 30/09/2022 | C1004 | 1007-010 | -88911.30443 | VAC |
| 31/10/2022 | C1004 | 1007-010 | -117753.5715 | VAC |
| 30/11/2022 | C1004 | 1007-010 | -103621.8845 | VAC |
| 31/12/2022 | C1004 | 1007-010 | -137239.2713 | VAC |
| 31/01/2023 | C1004 | 1007-010 | -120781.7129 | VAC |
| 30/09/2022 | C0000 | 1009-001 | -11414.361 | VAC |
| 31/10/2022 | C0000 | 1009-001 | -11817.43542 | VAC |
| 30/11/2022 | C0000 | 1009-001 | -12234.67362 | VAC |
| 31/12/2022 | C0000 | 1009-001 | -12666.50433 | VAC |
| 31/01/2023 | C0000 | 1009-001 | -13113.82061 | VAC |
| 30/09/2022 | C1008 | 1009-003 | 79989.22727 | VAC |
| 31/10/2022 | C1008 | 1009-003 | 81802.26833 | VAC |
| 30/11/2022 | C1008 | 1009-003 | 83710.02368 | VAC |
| 31/12/2022 | C1008 | 1009-003 | 85716.62069 | VAC |
| 31/01/2023 | C1008 | 1009-003 | 87831.4317 | VAC |
| 30/09/2022 | C1012 | 2001-000 | 11110 | VAC |
| 31/10/2022 | C1012 | 2001-000 | 11221.1 | VAC |
| 30/11/2022 | C1012 | 2001-000 | 11333.31 | VAC |
| 31/12/2022 | C1012 | 2001-000 | 11446.64 | VAC |
| 31/01/2023 | C1012 | 2001-000 | 11561.11 | VAC |
| 30/09/2022 | C1001 | 2001-005 | 134808.1692 | VAC |
| 31/10/2022 | C1001 | 2001-005 | 139568.6393 | VAC |
| 30/11/2022 | C1001 | 2001-005 | 144496.3893 | VAC |
| 31/12/2022 | C1001 | 2001-005 | 149596.4828 | VAC |
| 31/01/2023 | C1001 | 2001-005 | 154879.4669 | VAC |

I normally use the `arrayformula` with `split` and `flatten`  but I would like to Unpivot directly from the query formula

Comment: you cannot unpivot directly from the query formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(C1:G1&"×"&A2:A10&"×"&B2:B10&"×"&C2:G10), "×"), 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,'VAC' where Col4 is not null label 'VAC'''", ))
```

[image]

Comment: i indicated "I normally use the arrayformula with split and flatten but I would like to Unpivot directly from the query formula", I need the formula to work in one step without having an intermediary table including the query in it

Comment: @R_life_R can you share a copy of your sheet?